# How to remove wrinkles from puffer jacket?

Tags: clothing

I have a puffer jacket that looks something like this.

[image]

How to remove wrinkles from it. Its a new jacket, still it started to show wrinkles too early. I think the puff is compressed. What should I do? Anythin which I can do at home?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you can try is spaying the jacket with a mist of clean water, then gently pull the fabric to remove the wrinkles and let it dry.

To spray the jacket, you can use any type of spray bottle. If you use an empty bottle of a cleaning product, make sure to rinse out any residue. If you don't have a spray bottle, you can also wet a piece of fabric and rub it over the jacket to dampen it.

It's best to let the jacket dry while hanging. That way you reduce the risk of new wrinkles. A cloth hanger also gives you a good anchor to pull the fabric straight and remove the existing wrinkles.

However, there is a risk that the wrinkles won't smooth out. Especially synthetic fibers are prone to permanent wrinkling.